# PyPi Server firewall and port settings

Tags: python, pip, pypi, devpi

I am running [devpi-server](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) on a host to host some python packages on. On my laptop, I can download them using `pip install --index <hostname>`.

On another host though, running the same shows me a Package Not Found error. It seems like it is not finding the package in devpi-server host, and it is falling back to the global PyPi server.

I think that this is a firewall or port issue. What kind of firewall/ACL access permissions do I need for the host to see my PyPi server hosted by devpi-server? devpi-server is running on port 4040, and so I have port 4040 open.

I have attempted to put in a ticket in the devpi-server project but I've been going back and forth with the maintainer for a week and he doesn't seem to understand what the question is so I am hoping someone here can assist me.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:
Using devpi-client, I can install the packages properly. What is different with pip install --index? Does it need any specific ports open or certain permissions set up?